# Call url from view in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, ecmascript-6

I'm learning Laravel framework. In my application I'm sending an ajax request and then I want to call another page from success. I've already tried some suggestions but I 've got errors.

I'm using ES6 and my jsx files are converted to js file to **public/js** directory.

**resources/assets/js/** is es6 directory and **resources/views/appPage.blade.php** is view file

I also created appPage.blade.php file in public directory but this didn't work.

I post the trials and their resulst in comment line

```
 success: function success(response) {
                    if (response.result) {

                        // Request Url: http://localhost:8000/appPage
                        // Status code: 404
                        //window.location.replace('appPage');
                        //window.location.href = 'appPage';

                        // Request Url: http://localhost:8000/%7B%7Burl(%22appPage%22)%7D%7D
                        // Status code: 404
                        //window.location.href = '{{url("appPage")}}';
                    }
                }
```

Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need create view file in public folder,

```
{{ url("appPage") }} should be a route path that already exists
```

define a route in app/Http/routes.php that url is appPage, like this :

```
Route::get('appPage', function(){

   return view('appPage');
});
```

i think you need get more tutorials. [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) have a lots of tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already had Route as you said and I tried both `window.location.replace({{url('appPage')}})` and `window.location.href = "{{URL::to('appPage')}}";` but unfortunately I got the same results.

Comment: Now `window.location.replace('appPage');` or `window.location.replace('appPage');` are working with defined route.